# Submit button to create HTML file with text entered

Tags: php, html, css, forms, styles

Our chef at the place I work is trying to figure out an easy (kinda fancy) way to put the menu out for the employees to view. I have a form built already so he can enter the menu Mon-Fri but I need some help creating the menu.

I want the chef to be able to go to this website (already built form) that has him enter all the information for the menu. Once he enters the information he hits submit and it creates an HTML file, which will already be fancied up with background images and fonts, but I need his text he entered to transpose into there.

I took this information from a form I have currently that emails our HR department upon entering data. I know it has to do with the php piece I'm just not even sure if this is possible.

Here's my form, I'm guessing I just need the php information

```
<head>
<title>Cafe Menu Creator</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cafe.css" />
</head>

<body>
<br />
<br />
<center><h1>Cafe Menu Creator</h1></center>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="contact-area">
        <form method="post" action="cafe.php">
            <label for="Name">Monday:</label>
            <textarea name="Message_Monday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message_Monday"></textarea>

            <label for="Name">Tuesday:</label>              
            <textarea name="Message_Tuesday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message_Tuesday"></textarea>

            <label for="Name">Wednesday:</label>            
            <textarea name="Message_Wednesday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message_Wednesday"></textarea>

            <label for="Name">Thursday:</label>
            <textarea name="Message_Thursday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message_Thursday"></textarea>

            <label for="Name">Friday:</label>
            <textarea name="Message_Friday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message_Friday"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
        </form>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>



    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php



$MessageMonday = $_POST['Message_Monday'];
$MessageTuesday = $_POST['Message_Tuesday'];
$MessageWednesday= $_POST['Message_Wednesday'];
$MessageThursday = $_POST['Message_Thursday'];
$MessageFriday = $_POST['Message_Friday'];


ob_start();
?>
<div>
<html>
<body bgcolor=red>






</div>
<div><?php echo $MessageMonday; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $MessageTuesday; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $MessageWednesday; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $MessageThursday; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $MessageFriday; ?></div>



<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$path = '/var/www/web1/web/';
$filename = "menu.html";

file_put_contents($path.$filename);
?>
```

Comment: textarea's need to bear unique name attributes.

Comment: you edited but have another one here `$path = "\\server\c$\cafe;` so are we editing as I comment here? *lol*

Comment: oh and `$filename = "menu"."html";` is still wrong. that should read as `$filename = "menu.html";` if you're wanting to create the `menu.html` file. and your path has no trailing slash. which will read as `path/folderFILE.html`. rather than `path/folder/FILE.html`.

Comment: probably because you're not checking for them and could be a permissions issue on either the folder/path and/or the file. error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php plus, your textareas again, must have different name attributes and POST arrays/variables are case-sensitive. You're using the same name for them but different ID's, so if you're not using JS with this, your code will fail. depending on the drive, `\\server` should read as c:\\folder\\  etc. You're trying to access a virtual machine.

Comment: Updated original post with my changes. I've moved it to my web server so I will leave all file paths as they are now.

Comment: Make sure you change your textarea name so they correspond to the php file ;) ex:  <textarea name="message_Friday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Friday"></textarea>

Comment: Well Mack... if `$path = /var/www/web1/web;` is pseudo code, let me know. Otherwise, that needs quotes around it including a trailing slash. Again as I stated above as to how that will be interpreted. `$path = '/var/www/web1/web/';` - I don't know what else to say here. You've been editing too many times and there are far too many comments here. Wishing you all the best with this. *Cheers*

Comment: Last added note `$_POST['Message_wednesday']` and `name="Message_Wednesday"` will fail and the same for a few others. As I said earlier. Those are case-sensitive `W` and `w` are two different animals. And error reporting will tell you about that too.

Comment: So sorry, I was trying to rush through this and I shouldn't have been. I appreciate all you've done so far. I've fixed all of the case sensitive issues, and I looked into the error reporting but it I'm not sure if I did it right. here's what it told me - `Warning: file_put_contents() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/web1/web/cafe.php on line 39` So I'm assuming that's because it is pseudo code like you said. It is on a linux web server.

Comment: replace file_put_contents($path.$filename); with file_put_contents($path.$filename, $html); :)

Comment: Read the manual on that function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Got error reporting working :) I kept putting it in the file but then scolled further down to see what I actually needed to do. `Notice: Undefined index: Message_Monday in /var/www/web1/web/cafe.php on line 5` So just so I'm clear, which variable matches what? The textarea name or ID corresponds with the POST?

Comment: the `name` attribute, *always*. ID's are used mostly for jQuery and/or for CSS. I tested your code as it is now, worked perfectly. Your HTML markup is off btw.

Comment: To help others in your position, can you go ahead and accept my answer? Glad I could help :)

Comment: Awesome got it working as well, I had changed the `ID` and not the `name`. Thank you so much for dealing with my lack of knowledge on this. You guys are awesome!!

Comment: I just posted an answer after all the work I've put in here. *lol*

Comment: @MackMan You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't retype what I've put into comments with the debugging I've done.

The following is what the final code should read as, and you had some errors in your HTML markup which I fixed.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
<title>Cafe Menu Creator</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cafe.css" />

</head>

<body>
<br />
<br />
<center><h1>Cafe Menu Creator</h1></center>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="contact-area">
        <form method="post" action="cafe.php">
            <label for="Name">Monday:</label>
            <textarea name="Message_Monday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message_Monday"></textarea>

            <label for="Name">Tuesday:</label>              
            <textarea name="Message_Tuesday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message_Tuesday"></textarea>

            <label for="Name">Wednesday:</label>            
            <textarea name="Message_Wednesday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message_Wednesday"></textarea>

            <label for="Name">Thursday:</label>
            <textarea name="Message_Thursday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message_Thursday"></textarea>

            <label for="Name">Friday:</label>
            <textarea name="Message_Friday" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message_Friday"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
        </form>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>


    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$MessageMonday = $_POST['Message_Monday'];
$MessageTuesday = $_POST['Message_Tuesday'];
$MessageWednesday= $_POST['Message_Wednesday'];
$MessageThursday = $_POST['Message_Thursday'];
$MessageFriday = $_POST['Message_Friday'];

ob_start();
?>
<html>

<body bgcolor="red">

<div>
Menu
</div>

<div><?php echo $MessageMonday; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $MessageTuesday; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $MessageWednesday; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $MessageThursday; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $MessageFriday; ?></div>

</body>
</html>

<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$path = '/path/to/folder/';
$filename = "menu.html";

file_put_contents($path.$filename, $html);

?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

If you want to avoid HTML (and/or PHP) tags such as `<b></b>` etc., you can use `strip_tags()` against your POST arrays.

```
$MessageMonday = strip_tags($_POST['Message_Monday']);
$MessageTuesday = strip_tags($_POST['Message_Tuesday']);
$MessageWednesday= strip_tags($_POST['Message_Wednesday']);
$MessageThursday = strip_tags($_POST['Message_Thursday']);
$MessageFriday = strip_tags($_POST['Message_Friday']);
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

However, if you do want to add HTML tags to make **bold** text (on the fly), you would simply enter `<b>Today's menu</b>` followed by any other valid HTML.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element

---

Even an HTML table (on the fly):

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF">
      <p align="center"><b>Today's menu</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Fish and chips</td>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">$3.95</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Hamburger</td>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">$3.25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Cheeseburger</td>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">$3.50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would change your inputs name to something unique like `message_friday` or `message[]` instead of just `message`

and this php code should work, you still need to do some modification for the path and filename and insert your own html.

```
<?php
    $messageMonday = $_POST['message_monday'];
    $messageFriday = $_POST['message_friday'];

    $html = "";

    ob_start();
?>
    <div>Your html stuff</div>
    <div><?php echo $messageMonday; ?></div>
    . . .
<?php
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $path = "/path/to/file/";
    $filename = "file_".rand(0,9999).".html";

    file_put_contents($path.$filename, $html);
?>
```

If you want, you could wrap this into a function that returns the new Url :)

Comment: I can't seem to get it working. I've updated the original post with my php file contents now. Sorry I know nothing about php. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: File needs to end with `.php` extension and run it on a web server or localhost... how did you implement this?

Comment: It's locally on my PC at this time until I get it working then I will move it and change file paths to the server it'll stay on.

Comment: You need to have a php server running, and have your form's method point to the php script.